# Start dockerized web-sites on demand

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, aws

I have limited resources on my server and I want to host 50 different versions of my product. I have very complicated and unfortunately buggy product and I would like to keep every version accessible. If any bug reported we will be able to investigate and reach when exactly this issue first occurred.

But since each web-site has 5 gb of data and 1 gb of database, it's not possible to keep all web-sites open all the time. Our server gives mysql errors and server is not responding because memory overflow.

I was wondering if there is a way to keep those 50 different web-sites disabled by default. If someone tries to reach version-5-1.ourdomain.com show a wait screen and redirect when it's booted.

And if a web site didn't visited more than 30 minutes close it and release the resources.

Comment: Instantiate VM on some cloud provider on demand? Server resources aren't so expensive these days when you don't need high availability.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a better way, but you should be able to use a reverse proxy on the host combined with systemd socket activation. When a request comes in to the socket systemd can start up the container and forward the request (It will block until the container starts up and it receives the request), then have something watch the log files, and when nothing shows up in the access log for eg 5 minutes just stop the container.

Comment: To start a container with systemd socket activation you would need to use Podman. Podman supports socket activation since version 3.4.0 (released Sep 2021). Unfortunately Docker does not yet support socket activation.

I wrote a small example demo of how to set up _socket activation_ with __systemd__, _odman__ and a __MariaDB__ container:

https://github.com/eriksjolund/mariadb-podman-socket-activation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (wanting to start a web server on demand... not having 50(!) different copies running on the same host). The existing answer provides a perfectly correct solution, but some leg-work remains to set it up, and I also wanted something that would be easily deployable in a container-native environment, which doesn't play great with systemd.

For this purpose I created the following project which I am now running in production: https://github.com/radian-software/sleeping-beauty

It is not perfect, but may serve your use case, or may be adaptable to fit.